# My Task Is convert my string into uppercase in Multidimensional array

Tags: arrays

**I am Changeing string using array_change_key_case() function**

```
<?php
```

$emp = array
(
array(1,"sonoo",400000),
array(2,"john",200000),
array(3,"smith",350000),
array(4,"dev",500000),
array(5,"lora",300000),
array(6,"rahul",300000)
);
?>

**I am abele to change string into uppercase in associative array but in multidimensional uppercase is not working**

Answer (score 0):

this code snippet should be what you are looking for.

```
<?php    
$emp = array
(
array(1,"sonoo",400000),
array(2,"john",200000), 
array(3,"smith",350000), 
array(4,"dev",500000), 
array(5,"lora",300000),
array(6,"rahul",300000)
); 
foreach($emp as $row => $innerArray){
    foreach($innerArray as $innerRow => $value){
        if(is_string($value)) {
            $emp[$row][$innerRow] = strtoupper($value);
            echo $emp[$row][$innerRow]. "<br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```